# Run script in /etc/rc.local under specific user

Tags: 12.04, users, su, ownership

I am using portia (https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia) and I have set the following command in my rc.local:

```
cd /home/portia/portia/slyd && twistd slyd
```

Problem here is that the command/script get executed as root and all the files/folders that are created by the script have "root" as owner.

How can I run this specific command as a different user?

What I have tried so far:

```
cd /home/portia/portia/slyd && su jim -c twistd slyd
cd /home/portia/portia/slyd && su jim -c "twistd slyd"
su jim -c "cd /home/portia/portia/slyd && twistd slyd"
```

Nothing worked.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you see [sudo](http://askubuntu.com/questions/472175/why-it-is-sudo)?

Comment: I tried `sudo -u jim "cd /home/portia/portia/slyd && twistd slyd"` and different variations with and without quotes without success.

Comment: What does "nothing worked" mean in this context? Do you mean that the `twistd` command does not run when invoked via `su`, or that it runs but the resulting files are still owned by root?

Comment: what is the exact output you get from typing at the terminal `cd /home/portia/portia/slyd && su jim -c "twistd slyd"`?

Comment: bain, the command above gets executed successfully. portia runs. but using the exact command in rc.local does not start the portia server.