# switch to root access on a terminal session

Tags: 14.04, tag

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.

I would like to create a root user along with the admin account that was setup during installation.

The default admin account does not have a root privilege.

Comment: You do not need to unlock root. You can use sudo instead. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you start gparted, you will be asked for the password and you will have all privileges to create partitions. But you probably have problems, when creating partitions from a running system.

Comment: i was able to sudo from terminal and perform intended task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to create a root user along with the admin account that was set-up during installation.

Admin and Root are one and the same on Ubuntu, which means that this:

> The default admin account does not have a root privilege.

is wrong.

It really depends what you want to do with the root privilege.

If you need to edit a file, you need to use `sudo` in the terminal - for example this command will open a file called "file.txt" from root's home area:

```
sudo -i gedit /root/file.txt
```

If you are going to be running lots of commands, use `sudo su` first, then you don't need to keep typing `sudo`.

[This answer explains what `sudo` is and does.](https://askubuntu.com/a/472498/186134)

Comment: yes i got that concept now,one needs to understand the folder and privilege structure first. i was able to perform as root user from by running sudo passwd root and got the temporary root privilege, i was able to make a new folder on mount and changed the access level on that folder.

Comment: @AvinashMvrick if this solved your question, please click the grey tick below the down arrow!

Answer (score 0):

Any user in the 'sudo' group should have this privilege.

You can make a terminal root (if you're feeling brave and rebellious) by typing `sudo bash` but there is really no need.

Other users can be added to this group thusly `sudo adduser <username> sudo`

[How can I add a new user as sudoer using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line)